# animoto API options

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am using animoto gem for creating video by using image URL's.

I want to know is there any option that we can specify to choose template as there in animoto website.

If anyone specify all the options that will be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean the video style? According to this: http://rubydoc.info/gems/animoto/1.3.1/Animoto/Manifests/Directing, the only currently available style is 'original', so no.

Although IMO, original is the best one, and it allows for upsizing to 1080p full HD.

a